# rust-sfml linking with cc failed, how to specify lib/include/share path

Tags: rust, sfml

How can I specify where my libs live when building examples, or even writing new projects that use rust-sfml? I currently have both SFML and CSFML installed in `/usr/local/{include,lib,share}` as opposed to `/usr/{include,lib,share}`.

Is there a flag in cargo I can apply that will set the include/library path accordingly? Something like `cargo build --lib=/usr/local/lib --include=/usr/local/include`.

[here](https://github.com/jeremyletang/rust-sfml/issues/29) is the rust-sfml page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each library that links against C libraries needs to support the appropriate linker parameters, including finding the library itself. It appears that there is an [open pull request](https://github.com/jeremyletang/rust-sfml/pull/66) that adds support for specifying the install path to rust-sfml.

Specifically, Cargo allows specifying a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html). The build script communicates to Cargo by printing items to standard out. Two of those values that are interesting in this case are:

- `rustc-link-lib`— indicates that the specified value should be passed to the compiler as a `-l` flag.
- `rustc-link-search` — indicates the specified value should be passed to the compiler as a `-L` flag.

Comment: Thanks, for fixing this I ended up removing my current installation and using `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev libcsfml-dev` , and everything seems to work now.